# How to move stack list in other list c#?

Tags: c#

I'm working on a solitaire game.

I need help for move several cards from one pile to another.

I can just move one card to an other pile and I don't know how to change that because I use stack list.

So How can check another index apart the first index ?

```
       // valid card at to pile
    public bool TryPushCardsOnPile(Card card, int index)
    {
        Stack<Card> pile = piles[index];
        if (pile.Count() == 0)
        {
            return (card.getRank() == CardRank.King);
        }
        Card topPile = piles[index].Peek();

        if (!topPile.IsVisible())
        {
            return false;
        }
        return (card.IsRed() != topPile.IsRed()) && (card.getRank() == topPile.getRank() - 1);
    }
```

in Form Class

```
        public void PileClicked(int index)
    {
        if (IsDeckDisplaySelected())
        {
            Card temp = game.deckDisplay.Last();
            if (game.TryPushCardsOnPile(temp, index))
            {
                game.piles[index].Push(temp);
                game.deckDisplay.Remove(temp);
                move++;
            }
            Unselect();
            SelectPile(index);
        }
        else if (IsPileSelected())
        {
            int oldPile = SelectedPile();
            if (index != oldPile)
            {
                Card temp = game.piles[oldPile].Peek();
                if (game.TryPushCardsOnPile (temp, index))
                {
                    game.piles[index].Push(temp);
                    game.piles[oldPile].Pop();
                    if (game.piles[oldPile].FirstOrDefault() != null)
                    {

                        game.piles[oldPile].FirstOrDefault().IsVisible();

                    }
                    move++;
                    Unselect();
                }
                else
                {
                   // game.piles[oldPile].Push(temp);
                   // game.AddToPile(temp, oldPile);
                    Unselect();
                    SelectPile(index);

                }
            }
            else Unselect();
        }
        else
        {
            SelectPile(index);
            game.piles[index].Peek().TurnCardUp();
        }
    }
```

thank you

Comment: Please simplify your question, and post a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you're trying to do. Explain precisely what the code does now, what you want it to do instead, and what _specifically_ you are having trouble figuring out. It is not clear why using a stack is a problem for you, and it's also not clear why, if it is a problem, you don't just use a different data structure (e.g. some type of plain list) where you can add/remove elements at arbitrary locations.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  You need to describe a (clear) problem and ask a clear question to get a good answer.  `I need help` is not a question or a problem

Answer (score 1):

While using List or even custom linked list would be probably better choice, it is easy to move block of items from one stack to another: pop all, reverse, push to other stack:

```
 var items = sourceStack.Take(4).Reverse().ToList();
 items.ForEach(x => destinationStack.Push(x));
```